# Swift UI Application falling on Unit test cases

Tags: swift, unit-testing, swiftui, mvvm

I create the app into Swift UI . I wrote the Unit testing case . I have local json into test folder . I am expecting to pass but it showing it found the record 0 instead of returning total record . Here is the error message ..

**testTotalCountWithSuccess(): XCTAssertEqual failed: ("0") is not equal to ("40") - Total record is  matched**
Here is code for Content view ..

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject private var viewModel: FruitListViewModel
    @State private var filteredFruits: [Fruits] = []
    @State var searchText = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(fruits) { fruit in
                    NavigationLink(destination: FruitDetailsView(fruit: fruit)) {
                        RowView(name: fruit.name, genus: fruit.genus, family: fruit.family)
                    }
                }
            }
            .searchable(text: $searchText)
            .onChange(of: searchText, perform: performSearch)
            .task {
                viewModel.fetchFruit()
            }
            .navigationTitle("Fruits List")
        }

        .onAppear {

            viewModel.fetchFruit()
        }
    }
    private func performSearch(keyword: String) {
        filteredFruits = viewModel.fruits.filter { fruit in
        fruit.name.contains(keyword)
        }
    }
    private var fruits: [Fruits] {
        filteredFruits.isEmpty ? viewModel.fruits: filteredFruits
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Here is the view model ..

```
protocol FruitListViewModelType {
    func fetchFruit()
}

class FruitListViewModel: FruitListViewModelType, ObservableObject {

    private let service:Service!
    @Published private(set) var fruits = [Fruits]()

    init(service:Service = ServiceImpl()) {
        self.service = service
    }

    func fetchFruit() {
        let client = ServiceClient(baseUrl:EndPoints.baseUrl.rawValue, path:Path.cakeList.rawValue, params:"", method:"get")

        service.fetchData(client:client, type:[Fruits].self) { [weak self] (result)  in
            switch result {
            case .success(let result):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.fruits = result
                }

            case .failure(let error):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    self?.fruits = []
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the my Mock api class .

```
import Foundation
@testable import FruitsDemoSwiftUI

class MockService: Service, JsonDecodable {
    
    var responseFileName = ""

    func fetchData<T>(client: ServiceClient, type: T.Type, completionHandler: @escaping Completion<T>) where T : Decodable, T : Encodable {
        // Obtain Reference to Bundle
        let bundle = Bundle(for:MockService.self)

        guard let url = bundle.url(forResource:responseFileName, withExtension:"json"),
              let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url),
              let output = decode(input:data, type:T.self)
        else {
            completionHandler(.failure(ServiceError.parsinFailed(message:"Failed to get response")))
            return
        }
        completionHandler(.success(output))
    }
}
```

Here is the unit test code ..

```
import XCTest
@testable import FruitsDemoSwiftUI

final class FruitsDemoSwiftUITests: XCTestCase {

    var mockService: MockService!
    var viewModel: FruitListViewModel!

    override func setUp() {
        mockService = MockService()
        viewModel = FruitListViewModel(service: mockService)
    }

    func testTotalCountWithSuccess() {
        mockService.responseFileName = "FruitSuccessResponse"
        viewModel.fetchFruit()
        let resultCount = viewModel.fruits.count
        XCTAssertEqual(resultCount ,40, "Total record is  matched")// it shroud return 40 record but it return 0.
    }
}
```

Here is the link for Json ..

**https://fruityvice.com/api/fruit/all**

Here is the screenshot ..
[image]

Comment: You are using DispatchQueue.main.async, unnecessarily, in the fetch function so your test validation is performed before the published property is updated

Comment: Well . if you remove it will give you warning

Comment: Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.

Comment: Ok but then your unit test will need to handle asynchronous code.

Comment: You means to say use the combine for testing |?

Comment: No you need to use something called expectations, see for instance [this article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/testing/how-to-test-asynchronous-functions-using-expectation)

Comment: can you please refactor the code please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `testTotalCountWithSuccess` test is testing asynchronous code. When you call `fetchFruit` on line 23, an async operation takes place. Even though you are using your MockService, the completion handler will be called *at some later point in time*. This point in time is after you are checking against your `fruits` count on line 24 and 25. So by the time you are executing XCTAssert you have no value to compare against.

What you need to do here is to use [XCTestExpectation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestexpectation) as follows:

```
  let expectation = expectation(description: "Wait for async code to complete")
  
  service.load { 
      // after load completes
      expectation.fulfill()
  }

  wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 2.0)
```

In your case you'll need to update your viewModel's `fetchFruit` function to have a completion closure as a parameter that you can pass from within your test. Something like:

```
func fetchFruit(completion: ((Bool) -> ())? = nil) {
    let client = ServiceClient(baseUrl:EndPoints.baseUrl.rawValue, path:Path.cakeList.rawValue, params:"", method:"get")

    service.fetchData(client:client, type:[Fruits].self) { [weak self] (result)  in
        switch result {
        case .success(let result):
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.fruits = result
                completion?(true)
            }

        case .failure(let error):
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                self?.fruits = []
                completion?(false)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then calling it like:

```
viewModel.fetchFruit { result in ... }
```

Comment: can you please explain this line please service.load {. ? it should be viewModel.fetchFruit() ?

Comment: Yes, but you need to add a closure parameter to the fetchFruit method

Comment: viewModel.fetchFruit() { _ in
            expectation.fulfill()

        }

Comment: it shwoing error is saying that Extra trailing closure passed in call

Comment: Obviously - you need to add the parameter and call it from within the method

Comment: viewModel.fetchFruit()  { result in
            expectation.fulfill()

        }

Comment: I already pass the parameter but still same error

Comment: Which part of `In your case you'll need to update your viewModel's fetchFruit function to have a completion closure as a parameter that you can pass from within your test.` did you not understand ?

Comment: if you check the viewmodel code on that function , i am not passing any parameters

Comment: if you say to pass the closure parameters then How I will pass this parameters into Swift UI view

Comment: let me share the content view code ..

Comment: Ok . let me check . One minute please
Thank . that work brilliantly . Can you please why we can call the expectation ? and why it is now asynchronous ? . In you answer that will help me understand more clearly . Thanks

Comment: can you please check this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75664482/swift-ui-application-return-an-empty-screen